# MEAN Stack yo meanjs returns errors when creating new project

Tags: node.js, macos, meanjs, yo

I've been strugging to get this set up all day and keep ending up with the same issue... I wonder if anyone can help and I'm totally stuck. I've installed node.js and NPM using brew on my mac, that all seems to be working well and I got it running without any errors (eventually!)

When I run `yo meanjs` this is what happens....

```
You're using the official MEAN.JS generator.
? What mean.js version would you like to generate? 0.4.1
0.4.1
? In which folder would you like the project to be generated? This can     be changed later. mean
Cloning the MEAN repo.......
? What would you like to call your application? MEAN
? How would you describe your application? Full-Stack JavaScript with    MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, and Node.js
? How would you describe your application in comma seperated key words? MongoDB, Express, AngularJS, Node.js
? What is your company/author name? Jane
? Would you like to generate the article example CRUD module? No
? Would you like to generate the chat example module? No
create mean/package.json
create mean/bower.json
create mean/config/env/default.js
Running npm install for you....
```

Then I get the following errors (partial error result as its too long for this...450 lines!):

```js
   Error: Command failed: /bin/sh -c cd mean && npm install
    npm WARN engine karma@0.12.37: wanted: {"node":">=0.8 <=0.12 || >=1 <=2"} (current: {"node":"5.1.0","npm":"3.3.12"})
    npm WARN prefer global jshint@2.8.0 should be installed with -g
    npm WARN prefer global node-gyp@3.1.0 should be installed with -g
    npm WARN prefer global nodemon@1.3.8 should be installed with -g
    npm WARN prefer global node-inspector@0.10.2 should be installed with -g
    /Users/Jane/myMeanProject/mean/node_modules/.bin/touch: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `('
    /Users/Jane/myMeanProject/mean/node_modules/.bin/touch: line 1: `var touch = require("../touch")'
    make: *** [Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o] Error 2
    gyp ERR! build error 
    gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:270:23)
    gyp ERR! stack     at emitTwo (events.js:87:13)
    gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:172:7)
    gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:200:12)
    gyp ERR! System Darwin 15.0.0
    gyp ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/5.1.0/bin/node" "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
    gyp ERR! cwd /Users/Jane/myMeanProject/mean/node_modules/bufferutil
    gyp ERR! node -v v5.1.0
    gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.0.3
    gyp ERR! not ok 
    npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
    npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 Exit status 1
    In file included from ../src/bufferutil.cc:16:
    ../../nan/nan.h:261:25: error: redefinition of '_NanEnsureLocal'
    NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Local<T> val) {
                            ^
    ../../nan/nan.h:256:25: note: previous definition is here
    NAN_INLINE v8::Local<T> _NanEnsureLocal(v8::Handle<T> val) {
                            ^
    ../../nan/nan.h:661:13: error: no member named 'smalloc' in namespace 'node'
        , node::smalloc::FreeCallback callback
          ~~~~~~^
    ../../nan/nan.h:672:12: error: no matching function for call to 'New'
        return node::Buffer::New(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), data, size);
               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction I'm a newby to this and very confused as to why it's not working!!! I've tried removing everything and re-installing but I'm still hitting a brick wall at this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After battling with this all day I figured out the answer right after posting... The issue is with the node version `wanted: {"node":">=0.8 <=0.12 || >=1 <=2"}`

To fix this you need to....

1. Install homebrew versions `$ brew tap homebrew/versions`
2. `$ brew search node` will show you a list of versions you can use. Choose the best one for you and
3. `brew unlink node` to make sure it's unlinked then finally
4. `$ brew install node010` to install the 0.10 version of Node.JS

thanks https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/171530/how-do-i-downgrade-node-or-install-a-specific-previous-version-using-homebrew